# WPF query builder control

Tags: sql, wpf, designer, builder

I wonder if there is any sql query builder out there meeting these conditions:

1. Available as WPF control so that it can be integrated in my WPF app
2. At least support of MS SQL Server and Oracle
3. Visual representation and drag/drop support (tables, columns)
4. SQL expression as a result property (no fancy "user-friendly" meta concept)
5. Possibility to edit the SQL expression manually (with changes to the visual representation)
6. No need to build up a metadata model before

I already spend some time on the web with the following results

1. ActiveQueryBuilder is functionally perfect but does not fit 1. (lacks WPF support)  [http://www.activequerybuilder.com/index.html?from=about&edition=net]
2. KorzhEasyQueryNET does not fit 5. (SQL is not written back to visual) and 6. (metadata model needed) [http://devtools.korzh.com]
3. Query Objects is not a component but a standalone tool [http://www.query-objects.com/]

So, is anybody out who knows of an alternative?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, EasyQuery does not strictly require to "build up a metadata model before". You can create it "on-the-fly" taking meta-data directly from your DB. Here are instructions I found on their site: http://docs.korzh.com/easyquery/how-to/build-data-model-from-db

Comment: but in the meantime I started uaing ActiveQueryBuilder via WindowsFormsHost, perfect functionality and great support

Answer (score 0):

ActiveQuery has a wpf edition ,too, now